# JDK location on MacBook Air and Jar files for JavaFx?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

I am trying to convert an existing Java project to a JAVAFX project but I am unable to find JRE folder in Macbook Air with M1 chip and hence I am unable to add fx libraries to the existing project according to the below link :

https://www.javatpoint.com/javafx-with-eclipse

Can someone please help me as I am new to Macbook ?

Comment: JREs and JDKs are typically installed under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. However, recent JREs don't include JavaFX, which is provided as a separate module. See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: @James_D I was looking into /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ folder only but on mac its empty. Can you tell me how can I see all the jar files and all that are there because on windows I can easily see the files in this folder but here its all empty  ?

Comment: Try executing `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home` from the terminal.  It should result in telling you the location of the default JVM.  If that fails, try `ls -l /usr/bin/java` and see where it links.Then list the contents of the folder containing the `java` executable.

Comment: If you have Java installed (to the point that `java -version` works) then I believe you can locate where it's installed by executing `which java`.

Comment: @Slaw On my system, `which java` just gives `/usr/bin/java`, which is a soft link.

Comment: @Slaw not that I know of; but assuming `which java` lists `/usr/bin/java`, then `ls -l /usr/bin/java` will give the target. (So I suppose `which java | xargs ls -l` will do it in one fell swoop.)

Comment: But this will all be in vain anyway because as far as I know there is no JavaFX for the M1 chip yet.

Comment: Be sure you are looking in `/Library` and not the `Library` folder in your home directory.

Comment: "which java" gives me "/usr/bin/java" but  still there is nothing in there and I can't see the java libs

Comment: @mipa Does that mean I can't use JavaFx for my project in M1 chip mac ??

Comment: @greg-449 yes I am looking in "/Library" folder only

Comment: *""which java" gives me "/usr/bin/java" but still there is nothing in there"* What do you mean "there is nothing in there". That's either a soft link (likely) or an executable (unlikely). What does `ls -l /usr/bin/java` give?

Comment: Use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see all installed JDKs; I'm not sure about M1/JavaFX.

Comment: @James_D ➜  ~ ls -l /usr/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  138896 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/java

Comment: @Arvind You can run it in Rosetta.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (2021-02-07) there is only a JDK for macOS that runs on Intel... so it will be running under the Rosetta 2 emulation, but it should work.  (This will change soon, as the ARM port for macOS is well underway)

Install a build of Open JDK for macOS that includes JavaFX.  I suggest the Open JDK build produced by Azul called Zulu.  Be sure to get the full version with FX.  That just simplifies things related to the JavaFX modules.  If you use a typical build of OpenJDK, follow the instructions on OpenJFX.io to build your app with Gradle or Maven so it properly includes JavaFX.

If you have the JDK properly installed it will be found in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

With modern Java you won't find Jar files for JavaFX or anything else in there because the classes will be delivered as Modules, not Jars. (a la JPMS)